# JSP coding issues

Tags: jsp

I am retrieving the set of values inside a table from database in a jsp page then it is in the form of link. Now I want to click that value and move to another jsp page.

How to code the program so that it can recognise that value and it can move to the next desired page.

But I unable to do that.

please help me....

Answer (score 1):

Well, the steps are something like:

1. Query the database (with JDBC for example)
2. Iterate the `ResultSet` and add each link to a `java.util.List`
3. Use an object `Link` that has two fields - the href, and the text value.
4. This all is invoked from the `doGet()` method of a servlet - when you have the `List`, place it in the request using `request.setAttribute("links", linksList)`
5. forward to the JSP (`request.getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp").forward()`;
6. On the page use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/) to do the following:

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${links}" var="link">
      <a href="${link.href}">${link.text}</a>
   </c:forEach>
   ```